# `code' is not defined; perhaps you forgot to include "lhs2TeX.fmt"? When using lhs2TeX

Tags: haskell, literate-programming

I installed lhs2TeX from Linux Mint 17.1 repositories and get the following error when trying to convert the file.

```
`code' is not defined;
perhaps you forgot to include "lhs2TeX.fmt"?
```

Error line reported is first line of code in haskell

The calling line is:

```
lhs2TeX file.lhs -o file.tex
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
%include polycode.fmt
\begin{document}
```

The `%include` line is required, you could include `code.fmt` instead, but it will result uglier code blocks.